# C++ iterating with changing vector.size()

Tags: c++

I've written some perhaps naive code that is meant to remove elements from a vector that are too similar. The functionality is fine, but I think I may get unexpected results now and then because of the dynamic resizing of the vector.

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    for(size_t j = i+1; j < vec.size(); j++) {
        if(norm(vec[i]-vec[j]) <= 20 ) {
            vec.erase(vec.begin()+j);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this safe to do? I'm concerned about i and j correctly adapting as I erase elements.

Comment: `j` will skip the element proceeding the erased element. You shouldn't increment `j` after erasing.

Comment: i thought something weird was happening. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay better attention to where your elements are. It might be easier to express this directly in terms of iterators rather than compute iterators via indexes, like this:

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
{
    for (auto jt = std::next(it); jt !=; vec.end(); )
    {
        if (/* condition */)
        {
            jt = vec.erase(jt);
        }
        else
        {
            ++jt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `vector.erase()` returns an `iterator` to the next element, so you can replace `vec.erase(jt++);` with `jt = vec.erase(jt);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are safe here. Since you are using indexes, not iterators, there is nothing to invalidate by erasing an item in the container except the size, and the size would be updated automatically, so we are good here.

One more thing to consider is what effect does erasing an element inside the inner loop has on the stopping condition of the outer loop. There is no problem there either, because `j` is guaranteed to be strictly greater than `i`, so `j < vec.size()` condition of the inner loop will be hit before the `i < vec.size()` condition of the outer loop, meaning that there would be no unsafe `vec[i]` access with an invalid index `i`.

Of course you should increment `j` after erasing an element to avoid the classic error. An even better approach would be to start walking the vector from the back, but you would need to do so in both loops to make sure that `i` a valid element is never erased from underneath the outer index of `i`.